# Will writing bytes to a TcpClient's NetworkStream before the remote is set up to read discard bytes?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I'm setting up some sockets and came across some curious behaviour and was wondering if it was expected.

I have two threads on each side of the socket. The writers (one on each side) just grab messages from a queue, serialize them, then write the bytes. The readers (one on each side) read for a header and body of my custom protocol, deserialize the message, and fire an event.

Simple enough, right?

The curious behaviour I am interested in occurs when the client connects to the server then immediately writes message. The client can be so fast that that the server hasn't spun up its read thread by the time the client sends the message. If that happens then the server never gets the message. Messages sent after the read thread is actually calling Read() are successfully received and processed.

Is this behaviour expected? Is it expected that bytes written to a socket before anything is reading on the other side will be ignored by Read()?

Answer (score 1):

No, TCP receive buffers are created during the three-way handshake, the first read will see all data sent so far on the connection.

This is assuming you have a competent TCP/IP implementation.  If the other end of your connection is a minimal hand-spun TCP library on an embedded device all bets are off.

What's more likely is that one read is getting several messages and the recipient is forgetting to process any past the first.  TCP does not preserve message boundaries.  You have to include sufficient length and/or delimiting information in the protocol to recover those boundaries.  And you have to handle getting less than or more than one message in a read buffer.

Comment: Both sides are .NET. (I am running this in some unit tests) The header is a fixed length and includes the body length so I though I would have excellent control over how the bytes are being read. The read thread accepts input from the Read() method so it can keep reading after a partial message is received. Does the NetworkStream complicate any of this or should I just be using a the TcpClient's Socket?

Comment: If I add a sleep before writing the first message, it all works fine. I would think the sleep should be inconsequential, if all the bytes were accumulating in the buffer as expected.

Comment: I am also writing to the socket as soon as EndConnect completes successfully. Does the socket require any additional time to become ready?